# Hibernate tries to create same Entity/Table twice when @TableGenerator is used - how to avoid it?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity, javabeans

I am using hibernate with my J2EE app deployed on JBoss 6.0.
My database is Oracle 11i and Derby.
For generating primary-key (running serial Id) I use @TableGenerator annotation 
in one of my Entity (PersonDTO) - like:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "EDIS_PERSON")
  public class PersonDTO {
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name="TABLE_GEN", 
                       table="EDIS_SEQUENCE", pkColumnName="SEQ_NAME",
                       valueColumnName="SEQ_COUNT", 
                       pkColumnValue="PERSON_ID", allocationSize = 5)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="TABLE_GEN")
    private long id; 
    .
    .
    .
```

And I have defined the required Entity for sequence - like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EDIS_SEQUENCE")
public class EdmSequenceDTO {
    @Id
    private String SEQ_NAME;
    private long SEQ_COUNT;
    .
    .
    .
```

Everything works fine as far as sequence-generation is concerned.
But during the creation of entities (when the very first time I deploy my J2EE app), 
I see the following error in JBoss server.log file, though all my entities/tables get created successfully eventually.

```
14:04:16,817 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] Unsuccessful: create table EDIS_SEQUENCE ( SEQ_NAME varchar(255),  SEQ_COUNT integer ) 
14:04:16,817 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] Table/View 'EDIS_SEQUENCE' already exists in Schema 'EDM'.
14:04:16,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] schema update complete**
```

I believe this is "not" actually an ERROR. It looks like since I have a reference to `EDIS_SEQUENCE` as part of 2 Entity beans, hibernate tries to create it twice.
Firstly, when the EdmSequenceDTO is deployed and secondly when PersonDTO refers to the `EDIS_SEQUENCE` as part of `@TableGenerator` annotation.

In my `persistence.xml` file I have `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property with 
value="update". 
I need to have this value instead of "create-drop".

I wonder is there any way I can avoid the error reported by hibernate?

Comment: Nobody faced this error?? Huh !!

Answer (score 2):

If it is not yet solved - you should not map the EDIS_SEQUENCE table to an entity class.  It is used internally by hibernate.