# hibernate_sequence duplicate entries for sequence_name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I use hibernate with oracle .
hibernate_sequence table have duplicate entries for few sequence_name (One in lower case and another with uppercase letter)

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "service")
public class Service implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "autogen")
    @TableGenerator(name = "autogen", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Getter @Setter @Id private Long id;
```

Like

```
Role    5
role    11
SERVICE 16
service 75
```

Could be a duplicate of [Hibernate tries to create same Entity/Table twice when @TableGenerator is used - how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085386)

Comment: Do you get the same results if you try on a fresh / new database. You might have changed the name in the @Table over a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like the same problem as that other question, where the poster was trying to create both an entity and a generator table with the same name. It looks like you just need to clean up your names and make them use the same case consistently.